# PHP: Socket server interrupted by socket_recv()

Tags: php, jquery, sockets

I am writing PHP socket server, displayed here is error causing portion. I find out ***socket_recv()*** is causing problem, it only lets one computer connect. However, if I comment out ***socket_recv*** then its working fine. But I have to receive data also in socket server. Help me find out solution. Please also point out any wrong with code. JQuery part is working fine, hence didn't print it here.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    $host = '172.28.4.5';
    $port = 10000;
    $null = NULL;

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
    socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);
    socket_listen($socket);
    $clients = array($socket);

    while(true) {

       $new_socket = socket_accept($socket);//Accepting new connection/socket/client if any
       $clients[] = $new_socket;//Adding the new client/socket/connection to client array

       $header = socket_read($new_socket, 1024);
       perform_handshaking($header, $new_socket, $host, $port);

       /* If I want to notify if new connection is established**/
      socket_getpeername($new_socket, $ip);
      $message = "Welcome to WebSocket $ip";

      $array = array(
              'message' => $message
              );
      $message = mask(json_encode($array));     
      write_to_socket($message);

      $found = array_search($socket, $clients);
      unset($clients["$found"]); 

      //Going through each client
      foreach($clients as $client) {

             //Getting messages with loop how many packages for each client has
             while(socket_recv($client, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1) {

                      $array = json_decode(unmask($buf));
                      print_r($array);
              }
       }
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: can you give more message? what 's wrong?

Comment: I could only connect one computer. If I don't use ***socket_recv()*** its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that
the code  is wrong

```
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
    socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);
    socket_listen($socket);
    //$clients = array($socket);   <---- here

    while(true) {
```

it seems that you add the listened socket to array , you should not receive and data from  the listened socket.

Comment: Everything is working except ***socket_recv*** part.

Comment: because you receive the  listened socket ,so it error .

Comment: Did as you said, still same problem.

Comment: can you please try it by yourself?